# Binding Nested Object Select Svelte

Tags: binding, svelte

I am trying to create a dynamic Fieldset form data but the select input wont change the binded data

[image: Image of Test]

I made this Repl
https://svelte.dev/repl/0dff600bd5134fb59d19e6ca4cb98fe6?version=3.48.0

```
<script>
    import Fieldset from "./Fieldset.svelte"
    let name = 'world';
    let fields = {Connection: {Setting1 : 1, Setting2 : 2 }}
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>

<Fieldset bind:fields={fields.Connection}/>
<button on:click={()=> console.log(fields) }>
    Button
</button>
```

then my Fieldset

```
 <script>
        import Field from "./Field.svelte"
        export let fields;
    </script> 
    <form>
        {JSON.stringify(fields)}
        {#each Object.entries(fields) as [ValueTitle, Value]}
            <div class="mb-4 items-center">
                <label for={ValueTitle}>{ValueTitle} </label>
                Fieldset:{Value}
                <Field bind:dataValue={Value} />
            </div>
        {/each}
    </form>
```

Field:

```
 <script>
    import Selector from "./Selector.svelte"
    export let dataValue;
    let options = {Hans: 1, Christian: 2, Andersen:3};
</script>
Field:{dataValue}
<Selector
    bind:data={dataValue}
    options={options}
/>
```

Last The selector

```
 <script>
 export let data;
 export let options;
 </script>
    
  <select
  bind:value={data}    
  >
  {#each Object.entries(options) as [k, val]}
     <option class="p-2" value={val}>{k}</option>
  {/each}
  </select>
```

The Data changes in the First Layer but not all the way Why is that and what am i dooing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Object.entries` creates new objects which are detached from the source. If you modify the primitive results of that, the source object will not be affected.

If you want to modify an object's properties, you have to pass in the object as a whole/use the object with a property path or index.

E.g.

```html
<!-- In Fieldset -->
{#each Object.keys(fields) as key}
    <div class="mb-4 items-center">
        <label for={key}>{key}</label>
        Fieldset:{fields[key]}
        <Field bind:dataValue={fields[key]} />
    </div>
{/each}
```

Comment: that doesn't let you modify the KEY name, only the VALUE of the object.. I need aswell a way to modify the key name inside a {#each ..

Comment: @AlanDaniel: Then you should not use an object but an array of objects.